Is arch_free_page an atomic operation?
Can a mutex be placed in the arch_free_page function, or is this function required to be
fully reentrant for all processors?

No, the arch_free_page function can be called from an atomic context (such as an interrupt). It is not possible to place a mutex in this function as it is required to not block or wait.
The function must be written to support freeing the page atomically.

This answer would be more useful to future users if you provided references or other supporting evidence.
